# Updating cloud deployment which contains bigquery dataset in GCP

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to update a deployment I have made using the GCP deployment manager, however, I get an error saying the datasets in the deployment already exist. Is there a way I can tell my deployment to create the dataset when it doesn't exist and do nothing if it does. I thought that was the point of the `update` command. Below is the error I am getting:

```
code: u'RESOURCE_ERROR'
 location: u'dep23/dataset'
 message: u'Unexpected response from resource of type bigquery.v2.dataset: 409 {"code":409,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Already Exists: Dataset my-project:dataset","reason":"duplicate"}],"message":"Already Exists: Dataset my=project:dataset","statusMessage":"Conflict","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my-project/datasets"}'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the resource has to be created by the deployment manager or else you are going to have various issues. I had to delete my dataset and re-create it using the deployment manager and then it started working.